# What might a "redesigned" ant-sized human body look like?

Tags: biology, humans

What changes would have to be made biologically to make such a being feasible? I would like to stay as close to the normal human body as possible.

Edit: [This question](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/6936/what-issues-as-a-result-of-square-cube-law-would-a-human-scaled-to-the-size-of-a) raised a lot of issues with shrinking a regular human body, but offered no solutions to these problems. Additionally, in this scenario, the space around the body isn't shrunk, but rather, the human body is genetically redesigned, so there's no issue with atomic physics and whatnot.

Comment: Not quite the same question. See edits.

Comment: If you read all the answers, you would notice that that smallest mammals are much larger than your ants.  This has to do with being warm blooded and needing to much energy to keep from dying of hypothermia in a nice cool day.  Not much you can do about that and still be mammals

Comment: Cool, so an ant-sized human would need to be cold-blooded. <== The kind of thing I'm looking for.

Comment: The short answer to your question is: You can't. I don't want to explain why. Just read the answers to the duped question. By the time you've fixed all the problems listed there, you're not looking at a "Human" anymore.

Answer (score 2):

I guess the answer is it's biologically impossible for there to be an ant-sized being that is anything close to human.